# Use alert to print something else than text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, alert, qr-code

Im pretty new in React Native, and I was wondering if it's possible to use the alert() to print something else than text, in my case I need to print a QR Code (using an ID)

Actually I'm at this point :

```
async function fetchFirebaseQRCode(id) {
    const path = await firebase.storage().ref(`${id}.png`).getDownloadURL();
    alert(path);
  }
```

And by pressing the button I get the id in text :

```
<Button
    onPress={() => fetchFirebaseQRCode(item.id)}
    title="QR Code"
    accessibilityLabel="qrcodeButton"
    color="#000000"
/>
```

So the question is the next, can I print picture / QR Code in alert ? Or do I need to use a modal ? If so, is there a simple modal that I could use ?

Thanks

Comment: Nope you can't print picture/QR code in alert

Comment: use custom modal rather than using alert

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view. When there is a qr code, show it on the center of screen. If it does not exist, hide it.